# Create / assign object via C# EMIT IL

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, cil, emit

new to IL... trying to create IL for:

```
Dest CreateInstance(Source src)
{
   Dest d = new Dest();
   d.Test = src.Test;
   return d;
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(Dest).GetConstructors()[0];
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateIntance", typeof(Dest),
    new Type[] { typeof(Source) });
ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();
//gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);// source
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);// new Created
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
CreateCtor createdCtorDelegate;
createdCtorDelegate = (CreateCtor)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(CreateCtor));
```

this runs as above... but if I uncomment out the Ldarg_0, I get a "this operation may unstabilize the runtime" when I try to call the delegate.

Also, what do I need to copy the Test member over? assuming its a basic type.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Source and Dest and just simple POCOs.

```
public class Source
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public int I1 { get; set; }
    public int I2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public string S4 { get; set; }
    public string S5 { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public int I1 { get; set; }
    public int I2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public string S4 { get; set; }
    public string S5 { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT #2: Now, I have this... still get the destabalize error:

```
        ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(Dest).GetConstructors()[0];
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateIntance", typeof(Dest),
            new Type[] { typeof(Source) });
        MethodInfo miSrc = tSource.GetProperty("S1").GetGetMethod();
        MethodInfo miDest = tDest.GetProperty("S1").GetSetMethod();

        ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);// new Created
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);// source
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, miSrc);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, miDest);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        CreateCtor createdCtorDelegate;
        createdCtorDelegate = (CreateCtor)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(CreateCtor));

        Dest dd = createdCtorDelegate(s);
```

Get the exception when I call the createdCtorDelegate.

EDIT3:

ILSpy shows this:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    class ConsoleApplication3.Dest Test (
        class ConsoleApplication3.Source s
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2148
    // Code size 26 (0x1a)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication3.Dest,
        [1] class ConsoleApplication3.Dest
    )

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication3.Dest::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: callvirt instance string ConsoleApplication3.Source::get_S1()
IL_000e: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication3.Dest::set_S1(string)
IL_0013: nop
IL_0014: ldloc.0
IL_0015: stloc.1
IL_0016: br.s IL_0018

IL_0018: ldloc.1
IL_0019: ret
} // end of method Program::Test
```

So, I've adjusted my code to:

```
        ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(Dest).GetConstructors()[0];
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateIntance", typeof(Dest),
            new Type[] { typeof(Source) });
        MethodInfo miSrc = tSource.GetProperty("S1").GetGetMethod();
        MethodInfo miDest = tDest.GetProperty("S1").GetSetMethod();

        ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);// new Created
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, miSrc);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, miDest);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        CreateCtor createdCtorDelegate;
        createdCtorDelegate = (CreateCtor)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(CreateCtor));
```

Still crashing :(...

Comment: Can you specify "basic type"? Do you mean primitive type or struct or ...?

Comment: Are you aware that reflection emit is almost obsolete given that expression trees exist?

Comment: Protip: Dump you IL to a file and run PEVerify on it.

Answer (score 1):

> ... but if I uncomment out the Ldarg_0 ...

Your method should return a value, that means when reaching the `ret` instruction the stack has to contain exactly one item. The `newobj` instruction will create the new object and loads a reference to it onto the stack, so if you add more items to the stack without consuming them before reaching the `ret` your code is invalid.

> what do I need to copy the Test member over?

The fastest way to get valid IL instructions is to use a high level language, as well as a compiler and decompiler.
When you do this you will get something like this:

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void Dest::.ctor() //create new Dest object and push to stack (stack->Dest)
IL_0005: dup                                //duplicate the reference (stack->Dest/Dest)
IL_0006: ldarg.1                            //push the Source object to copy (stack->Dest/Dest/Source)
IL_0007: ldfld object Source::Test          //replace Source object with value from Source::Test (stack->Dest/Dest/SValue)
IL_000c: stfld object Dest::Test            //pop value and Dest object, and save value to the Dest object's Test field (stack->Dest)
IL_0011: ret                                //pop Dest object from stack for return value
```

Comment: can you see the update in the main post? I followed your opcodes and still get the destabalize error.

Comment: you are using properties and not fields like me, use a decompiler and see what gets emitted with properties, it should be `callvirt` opcodes with the set/get method as operand.

Comment: you are using a debug build that introduced local variables, you didn't declare these. Have a look at the `.locals init` statement.

Comment: okaaay... so I rebuilt in release mode and the code is pretty similar to what you posted and now its working :) thanks!... so one final question... if I write a hard coded method and build it, it runs twice as fast as this dynamic one. If I compile a dynamic DLL, it also runs twice as fast... why, when I emit the same exact code as the compiler, it runs much slower?

Comment: Well i think it depends on how you measure this. Did you create a delegate and gave the runtime the chance to jit compile your method before invoking it (by invoking it before the measurements)?

Comment: just tried that with no diff... the delegate is typed, so no boxing / unboxing either. One thing... to simplify the OP, I just gave an example of dest.Test = src.Test, but its actually setting 5 properties. So I have a loop that puts out dup / ldarg / callvirt get / callvirt set emits. Not at runtime... at build time.. I'm just looping through the props and doing the dup -> set portion multiple times. Same thing as the compiler. Maybe there is some optimization for that?

Comment: Yeah i tested it, some of this difference seems to be the delegate overhead but since is very fast anyway there is no reason to be alarmed. If you still want to know i suggest to ask a new question.

Comment: hey man... I figured out the performance issue :). Thought I'd share with you... we did: DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateIntance", typeof(Dest), new Type[] { typeof(Source) }, true); -- on my home PC, this takes ~200ms -- now instead, lets do:    DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("CreateIntance", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, CallingConventions.Standard, typeof(Dest),
    new Type[] { typeof(Source) }, typeof(Source), true);
-- now only ~83ms :)... making it a static method did the trick :).

Answer (score 0):

Your last code is close to correct, you just have to declare the locals you want to use:

```
ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();
gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(Dest));
```

Also note that the last pair of `stloc.1`, `ldloc.1` at the end is unnecessary, and is the result of compiling your code in Debug mode. Always compile your code in Release when inspecting CIL, as the code is much shorter and easier to read.

Your second version of the method was also almost correct, the problem was here:

```
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);// source
```

There is no "argument 1", since argument lists starts from 0 (for static methods, instance methods have `this` as the argument 0). The fix is simple:

```
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);// source
```